# Why don't I have a httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Ubuntu seems to come with Apache2 but in the `apache2` folder there no `httpd.conf`?

Why is the file lacking and what do I have to do to create it?

Comment: Worth looking at https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout to see the differences in file locations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html all configuration options have all been moved to subdirectories.

> ```
> httpd.conf: historically the main Apache2 configuration file, named
> after the httpd daemon. Now the file does not exist. In older
> versions of Ubuntu the file might be present, but empty, as all
> configuration options have been moved to the below referenced
> directories.
> ```

Check the reference link for the name and description of each subdirectory.

Answer (score 3):

this File httpd.conf is still exits in RedHat , Centos , Ferodra however Now This file does not exist in ubuntu.

- apache2.conf: the main Apache2 configuration file. Contains settings
  that are global to Apache2.