# Where do I put the information for Django in Apache2 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, django

The [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) tell me to put

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Into the `httpd.conf`-file. As I learned in [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215157/why-dont-i-have-a-httpd-conf-file-in-etc-apache2) such a file doesn't exist on Ubuntu. Where does it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Ubuntu 14, head over to `/etc/apache2/`
You'll see 2 sub-directories:  `sites-available` and `sites-enabled`
Add any new configurations to the sites-available directory, and then use the little a2ensite script to "enable" the site (creates a link to the configuration in sites-enabled).  Here's an example:

- in `/etc/apach2/sites-available`, create `mysite.conf`  (likely need sudo access)
- edit in all your configuration settings, as in the question and save
- `sudo a2ensite mysite.conf`
- restart apache

This nifty technique allows you to keep your configurations for different sites in separate .conf files, and allows you to enable / disable each configuration independently without ever touching apache2.conf.
To disable the configuration: sudo a2dissite mysite.conf